# Applying Custom CSS

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I have a CSS file in my site assetts.

I am trying to attach the CSS to a custom Edit form on a document library using SharePoint Designer.  When I highlight the text and then right click on the style and click on the apply style then the code on the page is not updated.  The little asteric on the tab appears meaning a change has been made prompting you to save the document.

BUT when you view the form the CSS changes have not been implemented....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

close your sharePoint designer all together from all tab and open it again. Also make sure the refrence url of the css file is correct. Also please specify where have you referred your css file. But first close your SP designer and try again.

Comment: I have tried that and restarted the whole laptop.  FYI I attached the CSS file to the page which is stored in Site Assetts

Comment: OK....Lets Try the below alternative:
1.add content editor web part in the page and adding your css scripts there.
2. Add your css scripts directly in the page under div below content template by adding style tag. <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 </div>
 <style type="text/css"> 
 </style>
 </ContentTemplate>

 Also can you provide the path reference of the css file.the url under which tag.Have you referred it in Main Content place holder? I am interested in knowing how you have referred it.. is it through CSSRegistraion or other way. Let me know.